# Can't create controller in my asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have three projects in my solution, UI, Service and Core.

When I add a reference to my Service or my Core projects, from my UI-project, and then tries to add a new controller In the UI, I get the following error message:

[image]

When I remove the references, it works and I can create new controllers.

Comment: This question seems to be lacking a [mcve], and thus I wonder if it should be closed. To the OP, or anyone who posts in these tags, is it possible that it is still answerable?

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that it is related to your service library somehow.

Check that `soundyladder.service` project builds successfully and that it is referenced as a project (rather than a DLL) in `soundyladder.ui`.

Ensure that you can (re)build the entire solution.

Comment: Yes, It builds without problem. Yes, I have referenced It as a project.

Comment: Well... I'd like to try and fire it up in an IDE, but if that's not possible I'm blind. All I can say is that there's something ... odd going on with the service library reference in the UI project  which is giving you issue when trying to create a controller. Usual candidates are a build fail, or a bad reference.

Comment: You could try clean / rebuild to see if that gives you any concrete error.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the solution and if there is any error then fix those issues. After that try to create a new controller. 
It worked for me!